# Laravel 8.0 Error "Action App\Http\Controllers\SkladController not defined."

Tags: laravel, routes, model, controller, undefined

This is my [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHt2x.png) in SkladController. I want to fetch data from the DB but it does show me anything because I have that error in the picture.

**SkladController**

```
class SkladController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $sklads = Sklad::all();

        return view('sklads.index')->with('sklads', $sklads);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('sklads.index');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'datle' => 'required',
            'mandle' => 'required',
            'marcipan' => 'required',
            'orechy' => 'required',
        ]);

        //vytvorit v sklade
        $sklads = new Sklad;
        $sklads->datle = $request->input('datle');
        $sklads->mandle = $request->input('mandle');
        $sklads->marcipan = $request->input('marcipan');
        $sklads->orechy = $request->input('orechy');
        $sklads->save();

        return redirect('/sklad')->with('success', 'Uložené');
    }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```html
<h3> Príjem v sklade</h3>
<br>
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\SkladController', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      {{ Form::number('datle', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ďatle']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      {{ Form::number('mandle', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Mandle']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      {{ Form::number('marcipan', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Marcipán']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      {{ Form::number('orechy', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Orechy']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
    </div>
  </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}       
@if(count($sklads) > 0)
  @foreach($sklads as $sklad)
    <br>
    {{$sklad->datle}} {{$sklad->mandle}} {{$sklad->marcipan}} {{$sklad->orechy}}
  @endforeach
@else
  <p>nenasli sa zaznamy</p>
@endif
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('/sklad', App\Http\Controllers\SkladController::class)
    ->except(['create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']);
```

Comment: Yes it is SkladController.php in this folder.  I tried but not work.

Comment: You need to pass the controller and the method in your `action`. You're only passing the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `action` in

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\SkladController', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

It should be

```
'action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\SkladController@index'
```

Usually you'd use the `store` method but you only don't have it according to your route declaration.

or you could use `route` instead.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'sklads.index', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

Comment: Oh my god REALLY thank you it works !!!